# How to define @DataProvider at TestNG Suite Level? i.e on testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using Selenium POM Model with TestNG Framework

There were around 200 Testcases and currently I am executing these test cases with a single Data.

I have created a different suites file based on the modules. The suites contain a number of test cases. E.g. SuiteA(40 TCs), SuiteB(100 TCs), SuiteC (60 TCs).

My Requirement is: I want to run TestNG tests with multiple data and I would like to pass data at the suite level. How should I achieve this?  without modifying the existing code.

I have used the DataProvider and read the data from JSON File, But how should I implement this at the suite level?

I want to pass multiple Data at the suite level. So that it executes the first SuiteA with a set of data.
[image: TestNGSuite]

This is what I wrote So far

```
  public class ReadData {
           @DataProvider(name="URLS")
            public Object[][] getData(Method currentTestMethod, ITestContext context) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Object[][] arrayObject = readDataProviderEntlJsonOFull();
    ITestNGMethod[] iTestNGMethods = context.getAllTestMethods();
    for (ITestNGMethod iTestNGMethod : iTestNGMethods) {
        Method method = iTestNGMethod.getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
        if (method.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(currentTestMethod.getName())) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(IndexAnnotation.class)) {
                          IndexAnnotation indexes = method.getAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.class);
                System.out.println("Creating the DataProvider between Start Index: " + indexes.startIndex() + " End Index: " + indexes.endIndex());
                return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayObject, indexes.startIndex(), indexes.endIndex());
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayObject;
} 


@DataProvider
            public static Object[][] readDataProviderEntlJsonOFull() throws IOException,
                                            ParseException {

                            JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
                            FileReader reader = new FileReader(UserDir + "//src//test//resources//URLS.json");
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonparser.parse(reader);
                            JSONArray productCodelist = (JSONArray) obj.get("URLList");
                            Object[][] returnValue = new Object[productCodelist.size()][1];
                            int index = 0;
                            for (Object[] url : returnValue) {
                                            url[0] = productCodelist.get(index++).toString();
                            }
                            return returnValue;

            }
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your question properly. You are passing the test data via testng.xml file? You want to know how to send data from DataProvider directly without this XML file? Did you try @Factory? Factory at the class level, executes all the test cases of a class for every data.

Comment: Requirement is to run multiple test suites files with data sets. How this can be achieved?